# How do I show literal javascript as part of normal body in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I have some HTML as below

```
<body>
<p><font color="red">Use script as `<script>alert('123')</script>` - must be a number</p> </body>
```

How do show it as is?  I want to avoid removal of script tags, and ensure the browser does not execute the script.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer — I don't think that element does what you think it does.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to display that in-line, you need to escape `<` and `>` with the entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
Use script as  `&lt;script&gt;alert('123')&lt;/script&gt;` - mu...
```

Comment: The `>` characters do not need to be replaced, but often are because they look strange when left unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up an example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ZYKpk/1/

```
<p><font color="red">Use script as `&#60;script&#62;alert('123')&#60;/script&#62;` - must be a number</p>
```

You must escape the html tags in order to achieve this.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code, not just a link.

Answer (score 0):

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZYKpk/3/

```
Use script as:
<pre>
    &lt;script>
        alert('123');
    &lt;/script>
</pre>

Or use script as:
<code>
    &lt;script>
        alert('123');
    &lt;/script>
</code>
```

Comment: Answers only containing a link are not welcome on SO. Please copy the relevant parts of the code into your answer.